# How use free() function in this case? using malloc() and realloc()

Tags: c, dynamic-memory-allocation, free

Can you tell me where i have to put the free() function for the array "arr" in this code? I tried to put free(arr) before the last printf() but in this way my output is wrong. I'm trying also to check if the memory allocated is free.

```
int *boh(int *arr,int n);

int main() {
    int a,i,n;
    int *arr;
    int *b;
    int size = 6;

    arr = (int*) malloc(size* sizeof(int));

    for (i= 0; i<6; i++){
        printf("Give me a number: \n");
        scanf("%d",&a);
        
        if(i != 5){
            arr[i] = a;
        }
        else{
            n = a;
        }
    }


    b = boh(arr,n);


    for(i=0; i<5+n; i++){
        printf("%d\n",b[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}


int *boh(int *arr,int n){
    int *a;
    int i;
    int b;
    b = arr[4];
    a = (int*) realloc(arr,n*sizeof(int)+sizeof(arr));
    
    for(i=5; i<5+n; i++){
        b += b;
        arr[i] = b;
    }
    
    return arr;
}
```

Comment: Rule of thumb: every pointer you've got via malloc/calloc/realloc must be freed via free once you're done with the pointer.

Comment: What's the use of `a = (int*) realloc(arr,n*sizeof(int)+sizeof(arr));` in `boh`? You reallocate and you throw away the `a` pointer, this is wrong and pointless. I think you want rather `arr = (int*) realloc(arr,n*sizeof(int)+sizeof(arr));`

Comment: @Jabberwocky: `arr = … realloc(arr,…);` is bad code because it discards the previous value of `arr`, which should be retained in case the reallocation fails.

Comment: @EricPostpischil yes of course it's bad, but not quite as bad as the OP's original code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can you tell me where i have to put the free() function for the array "arr" in this code?

There is *no* appropriate place for your main program to `free()` pointer `arr` because function `boh()` reallocates the block to which it points.  Thereafter, the pointer you have responsibilty to free is the one returned by `realloc()`, not the original one.  The original pointer must be considered invalid.  The two may in practice have the same value, but often they do not.

For that reason, your function `boh` also must not attempt to write through the original value of `arr` after the reallocation, as it does when it evaluates `arr[i] = b`.

These corrections are required:

- check the return value of every `malloc()` and `realloc()` (and `calloc()`) call.  These functions return a null pointer on failure, in which event you need to accommodate that in some way, such as cleanly terminating the program.
- After verifying that `realloc()`'s return value is not null, your function `boh` must use that value instead of the original value of `arr`.  A fairly easy way to do that would be simply to assign it to `arr` before the `for` loop:

  ```
       arr = a;
  ```

  In this case, that will also cause the function to *return* the new pointer value, which is the one you have responsibility to free.
- In the main program, free `b` after you're done using it (that is, just before the `return`).

> I'm trying also to check if the memory allocated is free.

C does not provide any way to test the allocation status of a pointer.  The programmer needs to track that themself. However, you could consider running your program under control of an external leak-checking program such as Valgrind.

Answer (score -1):

I think your program has a few flaws.

Here's a version without memory leaks:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define SIZE 6

int *boh(int *arr, int n) {
    int *a;
    int i;
    int b;
    b = arr[SIZE - 2];
    a = (int *) realloc(arr, (n + SIZE) * sizeof(int));
    for (i = SIZE - 1; i < (n + SIZE); i++) {
        b += b;
        a[i] = b;
    }
    return a;
}

int main() {
    int a, i, n;
    int *arr;
    int *b;

    arr = (int *) calloc(SIZE, sizeof(int));

    for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
        printf("Give me a number: \n");
        scanf("%d", &a);
        if (i != SIZE - 1) {
            arr[i] = a;
        } else {
            n = a;
        }
    }

    b = boh(arr, n);

    for (i = 0; i < (n + SIZE); i++) {
        printf("%d\n", b[i]);
    }

    free(b);

    return 0;
}
```

You must put a `free` to the pointers you created with a `malloc` or similar functions.

A problem I detected is that you were using `realloc` without passing the actual size of the array.

Using `sizeof(arr)` won't work, you must pass it as a parameter to the function.